# Loading PublisherAdView in Recyclerview

Tags: android, admob, android-recyclerview

I am trying to load PublisherAdview in Recyclerview and it is working fine and displaying adds, but there is an issue with loading time, The adview is out of the screen initially, if the recyclerview is scrolled slowly then the ad will be displayed, but if the recyclerview is scrolled quickly then the ad will not be shown to the user.

```
final PublisherAdRequest adRequest = builder.build();
samRecCellHolder.setMrec(publisherAdView);
publisherAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

As shown above I am calling the `loadAd` method in `onCreateViewHolder` method, can anybody please suggest me if I can preload the ad and show it when the recyclerview is scrolled?

Comment: Yes, you should try to load the ad first, and then in the bindviewholder just show when a view is supposed to be from an ad

Comment: Can you post any example if you have?

Comment: I don't have an example ready, but can you provide the code on your onCreateView, I'm not sure if you should load content to a view there

Comment: I have created a custom view holder to display adds, and this is the code in oncreateviewholder final PublisherAdRequest adRequest = builder.build();
samRecCellHolder.setMrec(publisherAdView);
publisherAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

Comment: does the load have a callback that you can use ? If so, in the callback try  call the notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: It doesn't have a callback, this is working fine, I am just trying to reduce the delay in loading the add.